# I don't want a row to be added to table if alert box appears

Tags: javascript, input, html-table, alert

I have a textarea where the user enters in their question and then clicks on the "Add Question" button to submit the question and adds the question in the table as a new row.

The thing is though is the user can incorrectly type in their question, then it comes with their necessary alerts. This works as the alert does appear but it also adds the question in the table, what do I need to include so that if the alert box appears, it does not add the question?

Javascript code:

```
function insertQuestion(form) 
{   

     var row = document.createElement("tr");
     var cell, input;
     var alertErrors = "";

     cell = document.createElement("td");
     cell.className = "question";
     input = document.createElement("textarea");
     input.name = "question_" + qnum;
     input.value = form.questionText.value;
     cell.appendChild(input);
     row.appendChild(cell);
     if (input.value == ""){
         alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
         }else if (input.value.length < 5 ){
              alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
          }
}
```

Question textarea and add button below:

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
<table id="middleDetails" border="1">
<tr>
    <th class="tblheading" colspan="2">SESSION DETAILS</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        Question Number <span id="questionNum">1</span>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Question:</td> 
    <td>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        <input name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
    </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Table which stores added qustions below:

```
<hr/>
<table id="qandatbl" border="1">
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="question">Question</th>
    <th class="weight">Weight</th>
    <th class="answer">Answer</th>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit questions to database" />
<input type="hidden" name="numberOfQuestions" value="0" />
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo?

Comment: I tried to put it in jsFiddle but the alert box doesn't work on JsFiddle, but it works on the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to short-circuit your function execution by `return`ing from the function *before* the new elements are created and appended. I also changed the order of some of your code, for instance putting the variables first and not creating the elements until after the `if` test.

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   
    var cell,
        input,
        alertErrors = "",
        // Note, this is just so it's declared...
        qnum = Math.round(Math.random()*10);

    // Note, I'm using the .value instead of copying it
    // Also note the .length on the second check
    if (form.questionText.value == ""){
        alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
    } else if (form.questionText.value.length < 5){
        alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
    }

    // Stop execution with a return
    if (alertErrors != "") {
        alert(alertErrors);
        return;
    }

    // Just put the new element code together
    var row = document.createElement("tr"),
        cell = document.createElement("td"),
        input = document.createElement("textarea");
    cell.className = "question";
    input.name = "question_" + qnum;
    input.value = form.questionText.value;
    cell.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    // Added this as well
    form.appendChild(row);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rUdhp/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you should validate data entered by user before adding it to table.

Just like that:

```
function insertQuestion(form) 
{   
    var alertErrors = '';
    if (input.value == ""){
        alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
    } else if (input.value.length < 5 ){
          alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question";
    }

    if (alertErrors) { // if alertErrors string is not empty
        alert(alertErrors); // show alert
        return false; // and do not nothing else
    }

    // your stuff about creating tr and new input goes here
}
```

Comment: Note, `input` is not shown as being declared in your example before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to return `false` in the onclick if you do not want the button to execute:

```
<input name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="return insertQuestion(this.form);" />
```

and in `insertQuestion()`:

```
...
if (alertErrors != ""){
  alert(alertErrors);
  return false;
}else{
  return true;
}
```